# Manual techniques for trajectory design

Tags: trajectory, trajectory-design

I am trying to locate methods of trajectory design that can be performed by hand calculations, specifically for low thrust methods of propulsion like ion thrusters. Can anyone recommend me any tutorials or text books with methods for establishing the Delta V requirements and fuel consumption values. The mission is self I am trying to establish these values for is a mission to Mars

Comment: One  reason space agencies were early adopters of computers is that hand calculations are a terrible way to calculate trajectories.

Comment: i am well aware my initial option was to stk astrogator however i was unable to get the software to work, i posted another quest a few months ago about it, unfortunately even if the method are not very accurate using them will help provide a base

Comment: The book *Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students* by Howard D. Curtis is a very great resource with a lot of handmade calculation examples, which is available online. Chapter 6 describes orbital maneuvers, such as Hohmann transfers and non-Hohmann ones. Chapter 8 covers interplanetary trajectories. You can probably find at least parts of what you are looking for there.